# Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I was working on a project in the android studio and the project was running on an emulator then I opened another project on visual studio code in parallel then I tried to run another project on the same emulator but this error appeared and didn't disappear even if after restart my pc and opening one project and made wipe data for AVD
the error:-

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\courses\flutter\project 2\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on sdk gphone64 x86 64.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the amount of memory allocated to the simulator is insufficient. You can remove previously installed applications on your simulator or increase the amount of memory.
Remove Apps:

1. Tools
2. AVD manager
3. File Explorer (folder icon, second in the list of actions)
4. Data/app
5. Delete all folders (this should not lead to any problems).

Increase memory:

1-2 is similar.

3. The third icon in the list of actions.
4. Edit
5. Show advanced settings

Then you can choose the amount of memory yourself.